# jquery get control Id inside details view

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a details view and in the edit template of the detailsview I have a asynchronous file upload control.
Can some one let me know How can I get the Id of the fileupload control using jquery/javascript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some markup code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having any markup to point us in the right direction, it's difficult to answer your question. The best I can do is point you to the jQuery selector that finds all inputs of type file.

```
$('[type="file"]').each(function (){
    //Loop through each file input
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

If you post some markup, we can refine this a bit.